# How can I push an element into an array of object with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my User schema:

```js
    const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      userid: String,
      username: String,
      pwd: String,
      login_devices: {
        type: Object,
        default: {
          currentDevice: "",
          devicesList: [],
        },
      },
    });
```

And my questions are:

1. How Can I push element into login_devices.devicesList ?
2. Can I use the query results to construct a model ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the required document and add the element as you would in a javascript object. Then use the mongoose `.save()` function to update the object.

```
const user = await this.UserModel.find({});
user.login_devices.default.devicesList.push(new device);
return await user.save()
```